# Checkbox value is not updating?

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

Here is one problem . When i check all ,all check boxes  are set true but if some of record , i unchecked one of record , the all check box should be unchecked .Its working in plunker but not in my work space any reason ? Here is plunker url https://plnkr.co/edit/9JeIuP1jC5hOG5hTpSZV?p=preview

```
            <div class="row">                                 
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" ng-click="isAllRecordSelected()"
                    ng-
           model="isAllSelectedForSMS">All{{isAllSelectedForSMS}}
          </label>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4"> Mobile</div>
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">Name</div>
  </div>
  <div class ="row"
  ng-repeat="friend in friends">

    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
      <label> <input type="checkbox" 
         ng-model="friend.selected"
        ng-change="userSelectedToggle()">
      </label>
    </div>
     <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4"> {{friend.mobile}}</div>
     <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">{{friend.name}}</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I copy pasted the entire code at my end from plunker and it is working fine for me...Can you please try clearing the browser cache and try again?

Answer (score -1):

Just correct your html

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-click="isAllRecordSelected()"
                    ng-model="isAllSelectedForSMS">All{{isAllSelectedForSMS}}
          </label>
```

replace `ngmodel` to `ng-model`